# Input of a fixed point DSP

Tags: signal-processing, fixed-point

i'm new to working with dsps and fixed point and i really need to know:
1. Is it the fixed point dsp that converts the float number to Q format or a device does that before feeding the Dsp?
2. Who specifies the Q format to be used. Does each DSP come with a specified Q_format or the programmer does that in his codes.
3. Can i have an idea of how to perform a simple say 4 by 4 fixed point matrix multiplication in c++?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

The format is usually fixed for a given DSP, e.g. Motorola DSP 56k family uses a `24 bit signed fractional format (Q23)`.

Fixed point is really just the same as an ordinary integer but there's an implicit scale factor. For most operations this makes no difference, e.g. load/store/add/subtract all work the same way regardless of whether the data is integer or fixed point.
When it comes to multiplication or division however the implicit scaling factor needs to be taken into account - typically there will be a shift after the operation to correct for this. DSP instructions take care of this automatically, whereas normal CPUs have to do this explicitly.

When you're doing e.g. a 4x4 matrix multiply you just use the DSP's native fixed point arithmetic instructions and the scaling is all taken care of automatically.